# How to access model's metadata or static data in hbs template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model like this

```
var model = Model.extend({
  id: attr(),
  profileName: attr(),
  email: attr(),
  role: attr(),
  ...
});
```

And now I need to attach to it some metadata/static attribute.

```
var model = Model.extend({
  id: attr(),
  profileName: attr(),
  email: attr(),
  role: attr(),
  ...
  viewOrder: Ember.computed(function() {
      return [get(this, 'id'), get(this, 'email'), get(this, 'role'), get(this, 'profileName'), ...];
  }),
  viewColNames: Ember.computed(function() {
      return ['Id', 'Email', 'Role', 'Username', ...];
  })
});
```

And then in the view I've got something like this:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each model as |userprofile|}}
    <tr>
      {{#each userprofile.viewOrder as |order|}}
      <td>{{order}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Which is not great, but it works, but i would also like to do something like that:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {{#each model.viewColNames as |colName|}}
    <th>{{colName}}</th>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
</thead>
```

(I am aware this does not work)

So my question is how can i read static attribute of model in template or even better, set metadata (viewOrder, viewColNames) to model and then read it in template, or if there is any other better way to handle this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get all fields defined inside Ember data model dynamically?

There is a built in each-in help that is able to iterate keys inside object object. Since Ember Data model is just Ember object this works for them as well:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/

There is also an blog post one it was added to ember which includes details about this helper:

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/16/ember-2-1-beta-released.html#toc_code-each-in-code-helper

So inside your template you can do something like this:

```
<ul>
 {{#each-in model as |key value|}}
   <li>{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
 {{/each-in}}
</ul>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, I want to name (names don't necessarily match keys) and sort all the fields in the model, so I can build a table with names in table head and cols arranged in defined order.

Comment: How about creating a property viewColNames but instead of hard coded values you would do each with eachAttributes for a given model? http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachAttribute But why not have a custom field inside your model where you store JSON object that defines columns that you want to display on your template. So your server would return a list of columns that you want to display and you can have a view order field and sort the, using Array primitive? I can scrap an example but should be straight forward like in your example but comes from a field inside model